# Using loops and creating count to create score in a knowledge test

Tags: r, loops, count, aggregate

I have a data set with 11 items on a knowledge test and the goal is to tidy the data and in the same step create a variable representing the participant's item score on each of the 11 items. The items have a different amount of correct answer options. In the code snipped below there are just the first 2 items on this test printed: factualPost_1_1_rw stands for the first answer option of item 1, factualPost_1_2_rw stands for the second answer option of item 1 and so on. The 0s and 1s on these items do NOT express what the participant did choose as a right answer. They are results of a prior coding and display already if a chosen answer option was right (1) or wrong (0) instead.

My plan is to calculate the score for each of the 11 items with this formula:

**((Abs. number of correct chosen answer options within an item – Abs. number of incorrect chosen answer options within an item) / Total number of answer options within item)) * possible score of item**

The "Abs. number of correct chosen answer options" shall be the sum of the "1" on the "factualPost_x_x_rw"-items belonging to one and the same item, the "Abs. number of incorrect chosen answer options" shall be the sum of the "0" on the answer options within one item. Relevant here is that the result of these two absolute numbers can never become below "0".
The number of "Total number of items in task" is just the sum of "Abs. number of correct chosen answer options" + "Abs. number of incorrect chosen answer options";
The "possible score in task" is set to "2 points" for each of the 11 items. If a participant shows NA on an answer option it is assessed as incorrect chosen answer option (0).

```
structure(list(id = c("AG07ER06", "AK08HN11", "AN04AD26", "AN04ND30", 
"AN04RG15", "AN24ED27"), factualPost_1_1_rw = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 
1, NA), factualPost_1_2_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA), factualPost_1_3_rw = c(NA, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, NA), factualPost_1_4_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, NA), 
factualPost_1_5_rw = c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, NA), factualPost_2_1_rw = c(NA, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, NA), factualPost_2_2_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 
NA), factualPost_2_3_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA), factualPost_2_4_rw = c(NA, 
NA, 1, 0, 1, NA), factualPost_2_5_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, 
NA), factualPost_2_6_rw = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
tbl_df [196 x 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ id                : chr [1:196] "AG07ER06" "AK08HN11" "AN04AD26" "AN04ND30" ...
     $ factualPost_1_1_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 0 0 1 NA NA 0 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_1_2_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 1 1 NA NA 0 1 1 ...
     $ factualPost_1_3_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 0 0 0 NA NA 0 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_1_4_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 0 1 NA NA 1 1 0 ...
     $ factualPost_1_5_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 0 1 1 NA NA 1 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_2_1_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 0 0 0 NA NA 1 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_2_2_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 0 0 NA NA 1 1 1 ...
     $ factualPost_2_3_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 1 1 NA NA 1 1 1 ...
     $ factualPost_2_4_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 0 1 NA NA 1 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_2_5_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 0 1 NA NA 1 0 0 ...
     $ factualPost_2_6_rw: num [1:196] NA NA 1 1 1 NA NA 1 1 1 ...
```

```
***Edited***
Here comes how the table should look like in the end (presented just for the first item with its 5 answer options and for the first 5 participants): 

 id             Item              N        Answered  CorrectlyAnswered IncorrectlyAnswered  Score
 <chr>         <chr>              <int>     <int>            <dbl>               <int>    <dbl>
 AG07ER06  factualPost_1_tot_rw     5          5                 0                   5         0
 AK08HN11  factualPost_1_tot_rw     5          5                 0                   5         0    
 AN04AD26  factualPost_1_tot_rw     5          5                 2                   3         0 #(2-3=0; 0/5=0*2=0)
 AN04ND30  factualPost_1_tot_rw     5          5                 2                   3         0
 AN04RG15  factualPost_1_tot_rw     5          5                 3                   2         1.2 #(4-1=3; 3/5=0.6*2=1.2)
```

Comment: I feel you're making life unnecessarily hard for yourself by insisting on using an un[tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)
 data format.  With a tidy format with, say, columns for `Respondant`, `Item`  and `Response`, your life will be easier, your code will be more robust, more understandable and easier to maintain - and you will be able to avoid loops altogether, meaning that your code will also run faster.

Comment: @Limey, thank you very much for your answer. I don't know if I understand you correctly (probably bec. I am not a programmer), but actually I am using a wide format already. I have first a id column, then all the items of the knowledge test as columns and my question aims at receiving variables also as new columns. Maybe I chose a bad way of displaying my data (since it looks maybe like I am having a long format) but don't know how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment, I meant precisely the opposite of what you seem to have thought I meant.  Your data are untidy *because* you are using a wide format rather than a long one.  Your data are untidy in long format because the column names contain information necessary to perform your analysis: namely, the items by which you want to summarise.

You haven't provided any expected output, and your explanation isn't 100% clear to me, but I think the following code gets close to what you want.  The call to `pivot_longer()` tidies your data, the calls to `group_by()` and 'summarise()` calculate the statistics you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id,
    names_to="Item",
    values_to="Response"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  summarise(
    N=n(),
    Answered=sum(!is.na(Response)),
    CorrectlyAnswered=sum(Response, na.rm=TRUE),
    IncorrectlyAnswered=sum(Response == 0, na.rm=TRUE),
    Score=2*(CorrectlyAnswered - IncorrectlyAnswered)/N,
    .groups="drop"
  )
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   Item                   N Answered CorrectlyAnswered IncorrectlyAnswered  Score
   <chr>              <int>    <int>             <dbl>               <int>  <dbl>
 1 factualPost_1_1_rw     6        3                 1                   2 -0.333
 2 factualPost_1_2_rw     6        3                 3                   0  1    
 3 factualPost_1_3_rw     6        3                 0                   3 -1    
 4 factualPost_1_4_rw     6        3                 2                   1  0.333
 5 factualPost_1_5_rw     6        3                 2                   1  0.333
 6 factualPost_2_1_rw     6        3                 0                   3 -1    
 7 factualPost_2_2_rw     6        3                 1                   2 -0.333
 8 factualPost_2_3_rw     6        3                 3                   0  1    
 9 factualPost_2_4_rw     6        3                 2                   1  0.333
10 factualPost_2_5_rw     6        3                 2                   1  0.333
11 factualPost_2_6_rw     6        3                 3                   0  1
```

Two simple reasons why I feel this approach is better than working with data in wide format: the code (a) avoids any need for loops and (b) is robust to both the number of items being summarised and the label used to identify each of them.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked well! The only thing that did not work but I forgot to explicitly mention this is to evaluate the score by id. Could you please tell me how the command has to look like then? I tried group_by(id, Item) but this does not lead to the desired result. Thank you

Comment: I think `group_by(id, item)` should have worked.  "...does not lead to the desired result" is not helpful because it doesn't describe what your desired result is.  Does `group_by(id)` come closer to what you want, perhaps?  If not, please post another question and *clearly* define the expected output and provide sufficient test data to enable solutions to be tested.

Comment: thank you very much. With your given ideas, I did adapt my question and provided a concrete example on how the data should look like in the end. Think I was on the wrong way before.